# Java Regex match with grouping using ()

Tags: java, regex

When trying to match using this regex:

```
TEST_([[a-z]+[0-9]*-){0,1}DD[0-9]{0,2}-ENV
```

I get an error:

```
Unable to execute regular expression. java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal character range near index 20 TEST_([[a-z]+[0-9]*-){0
```

This regex matches in javascript but apparently not java. Can somehow show me how to group with () properly?

I am trying to match these patterns

```
TEST_DD-ENV
TEST_DD2-ENV
TEST_TEST-DD-ENV
TEST_TEST2-DD-ENV
```

Comment: Should the first `[` be there? Did you try double escaping the first `[` like `TEST_(\\[[a-z]+[0-9]*-){0,1}DD[0-9]{0,2}-ENV` Can you add an example of what you are trying to match?

Comment: Also `{0,1}` can be replaced with `?`

Comment: What text do you want to match? Please provide an example

Comment: Thanks for inputs. Added the patterns I'm trying to match.

Comment: Thanks @Thefourthbird. I could not for the life of me, see the extra [. that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

This should be your pattern: `TEST_([a-zA-Z]+[0-9]*-)?DD[0-9]{0,2}-ENV`

Removed unnecessary `[`

`{0, 1}` can be replaced with `?`

Since you were using uppercase alphabets, you must accept them too. So I included `A-Z`

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String pattern = "TEST_([a-zA-Z]+[0-9]*-)?DD[0-9]{0,2}-ENV";
        boolean result = Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher("TEST_TEST2-DD-ENV").matches();
        System.out.println(result);

    }
}
```

Result is: `true`